# Renamed repository and stack not listed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I recently announced a repository and stack via the mailing list (both called "teleop").

It was brought to my attention that in between the time I started work on my stack and the time I announced it, someone else had released a package with the same name as my repository/stack.  It was also brought to my attention that the indexer doesn't like it when a repository and stack have the same name (basically, the stack wasn't indexed).

So I then announced to the mailing list that the repository had been renamed to "skynetish-ros-pkg", and the stack had been renamed to "generic_teleop".

Per the email, the rosinstall file for the "skynetish-ros-pkg" repository is at:

- Github: https://github.com/skynetish/skynetish-ros-pkg
- Source: https://github.com/skynetish/skynetish-ros-pkg.git
- Raw: https://raw.github.com/skynetish/skynetish-ros-pkg/master/skynetish-ros-pkg.rosinstall

And the "generic_teleop" stack is available at:

- Github: https://github.com/skynetish/generic_teleop
- Source: https://github.com/skynetish/generic_teleop.git
- Docs: https://github.com/skynetish/generic_teleop/wiki

This information has yet to propagate to the software list at http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php.  Instead the old "teleop" repository is still listed, along with the contained packages, with no corresponding stack.

Could someone check why the new repository and stack have not been indexed?  Perhaps the old repository entry simply hasn't been removed, and it has a higher priority than the new one?

Best,
Kevin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29560/renamed-repository-and-stack-not-listed/) by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 357 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository indexers have been offline for several days due to a code regression.  Please be patient while we get the indexer running again.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2012-03-12**:
Thanks for the response.  Out of curiosity, is there a page where the current status or "last successful run" of the indexer can be viewed?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-12**:
There are two indexers: http://build.willowgarage.com/job/rosbrowse_rosdoc/ http://build.willowgarage.com/job/osdoc/

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2012-03-12**:
Great, thanks!

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2012-03-13**:
The indexer seems to have caught up, and my stack and packages and stacks are properly listed, thanks!  One problem though, my repository is now listed as "generic_teleop" instead of "skynetish-ros-pkg".  Is there something wrong with my rosinstall file?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-13**:
Don't worry about it.  You can use the 'skynetish-ros-pkg' name with ROS wiki macros, e.g. RepoHeader.  The browse indexer still uses the actual, physical SCM repository ID.

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2012-03-13**:
OK, thanks.